# Suddenly i am getting a runtime error when using fontawesome Library in my react Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, icons, font-awesome

I am getting this run time error so anyone has any idea what is is?(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eeWu.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eeWu.png)

I am using fontawesome library for icons in my react application but don't know from past 2 days am getting this runtime error.

I have also deleted the node modules and package-lock.json multiple time but still same issue is there so nay help or lead would be helpful.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: was there some upgrade in something somewhere?

Comment: the error shows `fortawesome` instead of `fontawesome`, Is the name is correct?

Comment: @BadPiggie yes it is fortawesome